# MFMessageComposeViewController auto-dismissal

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, user-interface, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In my app, I present the user with an MFMessageViewController, and after 10 seconds, I auto-dismiss it by calling

```
[self.presentedViewController performSelector:@selector(dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:) 
    withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] afterDelay:10];
```

The problem is, if the user has begun using the MFM (i.e. adding a recipient by either typing or hitting the plus sign or editing the body), I have no way to cancel this call. I know that I could call

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self.presentedViewController 
    selector:@selector(dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:) object:[NSNumber 
    numberWithBool:YES]];
```

but I have no way of knowing when the user has started editing the MFM in the ways described above. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you leave the dismissal of the `MFMessageViewController` to the user. The user has invoked it &  he would be the best judge when to dismiss it. In this case auto-dismiss I think is not safe & might piss off the user in some cases.

Its just not intuitive. Why would you want to dismiss in 10 secs? Just let it be.

> Everything should be made as simple as possible, but no simpler —
>   Albert Einstein

Comment: Yes, but in this case, if the user is not paying attention and doesn't dismiss the MFM, then the effectiveness of the rest of the app is compromised. I don't want to leave something like that up to chance; is there not any way to receive a notification when the user begins to interact with the MFM?

Comment: what do you mean "effectiveness of the app is compromised"? User opened the mailCompose window for a reason. Let him decide when he wants to close it. In this case any other way would be counter-intuitive & just not right...

Comment: No, because the user might not expect the MFM to appear the first time, and it takes a few seconds for it to be created/message body to be formed. The real meat of the app doesn't happen until the MFM is dismissed, which is why I have a timer. I don't want a user to start the app, then immediately put their device to sleep, expecting the app to work, and come back three hours later to see the MFM staring at him and no data recorded.

Answer (score 1):

As Srikar already pointed out, this might be a bad idea and not something a user would expect.

That said, you could observe the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` notification. Any interaction with the mail view controller would bring up the keyboard, so if the user does nothing, it wouldn't show up. Of course, there's no guarantee that the user actually typed anything, but I think this is the closest you'll get.